# CentOS 7 Installation Problem: Mouse Not Working

Tags: centos, usb, system-installation

I'm trying to install CentOS 7 on a Dell Vostro 410. I don't think the Dell has a problem itself. When I boot up into the BIOS, the mouse's laser is working fine. During installation the mouse works fine. But after installing CentOS 7, bootup at one point disables the mouse (the laser stops shining). I've noticed a message during bootup that says something like

```
usb_serial_init: usb_register failed
```

or something similar. It says

```
returning with error -19
```

How to fix? Thanks for your time! I'm trying to learn CentOS, so step-by-step instructions would be better for me than high-level instructions like *"edit the ______ file to allow ______"*. I've just now noticed that it also says

```
Fast TSC Calibration failed.
```

I don't know if that's relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem tangentially by finding out that the Red Hat Developers program allows you to download and install RHEL Server for free - provided you don't use the resulting computer for production. So I've installed RHEL Server 7.3, and it didn't have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the similar case with this one.
In my case, it occurs with a certain mouse.
My used mouse worked well on Windows 10 and BIOS setting, but it didn't work at all from installation screen of CentOS 7.5.
After finished installation and updated all the packages with only keyboard, the mouse still didn't work.

But, I change the used mouse, it has no problem.
I don't know why, but CentOS seems not to recognize some mouses.